# Full time vacuum pump/powered by solar array and battery

Tags: solar-cell, battery-operated

I am putting together a vapor extraction system consisting of a small 12 volt (500 mA to 1 A) 6-10 Watt, rotary vane vacuum pump, powered by a solar array with controllers and battery. My goal would be to have the pump run 24/7 (and I could install 2 or three pumps on timers to allow cool down). Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: hm, what is the larger context of this? If you have heat problems, then the time when you especially want to spend a lot of energy, ie. when the sun is strongest, might be a time when you *can't* spend a lot of energy because things get too hot. So, what is it that you want to build?

Comment: Thanks. Heat isn't a real problem typically but I thought I might get better life is I stagger the motor times.